# GitHub REST API for retrieving entities by id

Tags: github-api

I want to use GitHub REST API to retrieve information about users, repositories, and organizations. In my service I need to store a unique key for each of those entities. I was thinking of the user handle, repository and org names, but then read about the possibility of renaming each of them. Seems the numeric `id` field is immutable, so I want to store that one. And for each of these three entities there are two endpoints - one for retrieving by the names, another by id:

| Entity | API endpoint by name | API endpoint by id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user | `/users/{username}` | `/user/{user_id}` |
| org | `/orgs/{org_name}` | `/orgs/{org_id}` and `/organizations/{org_id}` |
| repo | `/repos/{owner}/{repo}` | `/repositories/{repo_id}` |

Everything works as expected. The only issue is that the APIs that accept `id` are not publicly/officially documented in their REST API documentation. Now I wonder if I can take dependency on those, or they are deprecated, or will be deprecated soon. Would appreciate if someone with insider knowledge can respond.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have insider knowledge of the GitHub REST API or its roadmap. However, consider the following request:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-table
```

This repository, `tannerlinsley/react-table`, was transferred to a new organization and renamed `TanStack/table`. As a result, the request above has the following 301 response:

```json
{
  "message": "Moved Permanently",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repositories/71487058",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/v3/#http-redirects"
}
```

While this does not guarantee the long term efficacy of these routes, you can take some solace in the fact that GitHub "officially" uses them in this case. (I have no data about whether this also occurs for users and organizations.)